# Nested functions: Error: CONTAINS statement at (1) is already in a contained program unit

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I've programmed a module that computes an integral of a given function f(x). Now I want to compute the integral of a product of functions in a Fortran main program.

The main program is:

```
program exercici3
!Let's import the gquad function from legendre for integrals
use legendre

implicit none

contains

subroutine comp_average_dist(psi)
    !Compute the integral of psi(x)*x*psi(x)
    real(8) :: x_bar
    interface
        function psi(x) result(f)
            real(8) :: x,f
        end function
    end interface

    x_bar = gquad(sandwich_dist,1000,0,1d30)

    contains

    function sandwich_dist(x) result(sand)
        real(8) :: x,sand
          sand = psi(x)*x*psi(x)
    end function sandwich_dist
end subroutine
end program
```

The problem that I have is when I compile my program with gfortran 4.8.4 it raises the next error:

```
Error: CONTAINS statement at (1) is already in a contained program unit
```

I search the way to put nested functions in Fortran [here](http://www.fortran90.org/src/rosetta.html#nested-functions). Do you see the error?

Comment: Ok I create a new module with the function and works perfectly

Comment: See on the same page what to do instead of the ugly `real(8)` http://www.fortran90.org/src/rosetta.html#floating-point-numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are calling "nested functions" are, in terms of the Fortran language, *internal subprograms*.

The documention you link to is largely correct about such contained functions, but there is an important aspect neglected and the source of the error: an internal procedure may not itself contain another internal procedure.

For the example in the question, `comp_average_dist` is an internal subroutine of the main program.  `sandwich_dist` is an attempt to create an internal function of that subroutine, and the compiler rightly complains.

As you note in your comment, if `comp_average_dist` is a module procedure it is then allowed to have an internal function.  `sandwich_dist` will have access to the host subroutine and module.